# How do we fetch latest packer release in buildspec.yml?

Tags: amazon-web-services, packer

We are trying to build AMI using packer in a codepipeline, presently we hardcode the packer link, something like:

```
"wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/packer/0.12.2/packer_0.12.2_linux_amd64.zip
-O /tmp/packer.zip"
```

I would want to be able to fetch the latest packer build, can somebody help in terms of how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
current_version=$(curl -s https://checkpoint-api.hashicorp.com/v1/check/packer | jq -r .current_version)
wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/packer/${current_version}/packer_${current_version}_linux_amd64.zip
```

See this issue [#5120](https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/5120)

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, when I am putting this in packer buildspec.yml its not working:
[Container] 2017/07/20 09:26:38 Running command current_version=$(curl -s https://checkpoint-api.hashicorp.com/v1/check/packer | > jq -r .current_version)
sh: 1: -r: not found


 current_version=$(curl -s https://checkpoint-api.hashicorp.com/v1/check/packer | > jq -r .current_version) exit status 127

COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: current_version=$(curl -s https://checkpoint-api.hashicorp.com/v1/check/packer | > jq -r .current_version)

Comment: I fixed a typo in the example. Also ensure that you have `jq` istalled.